# ServerError due to Memory issues?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my Project (ASP.NET, VB.NET), sometimes a `Server Error` is showing.
When this error is shown, Users cannot submit their Applications, so that they have to re-type full details and submit again.
How can I escape from these Server Errors?

I think the reason may be Memory issues. Because if the user try to submit again (after Sign Out->Sign In ) then they can submit. Daily twice or thrice Error is happening.

Comment: can you specify a specific error? "Server Error" could mean a lot of different things.

Comment: do you mean the big red 'Server Error' message that really says nothing else. or a server error where it shows several yellow boxes on a white background?

Comment: Error is solved by increasing the  Maximum pool size to 500 in web.config 
Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I think that you'll need to provide a bit more info to get meaningful solutions.

- Do you have server logs?
- Can you debug through the app as the error occurs?
- Does the error occur at a certain time of day, or after a certain regular action?
- Does your app attempt to write to a file that may not be accessible?
- is it possible that you are experiencing memory issues?

the list could go on, best to do some more investigation and if a more specific issue comes to light edit your question with the extra detail.

**AFTER EDIT:**

From the extra detail you've provided I wouldn't jump to memory as an issue, in signing out and back in the user is refreshing their session so everything is reset. If you are not seeing anything in your logs you'll need to look at your exception/error handling.

You just haven't provided enough info yet for us to work out the root issue, let alone suggest a solution. That's what you're seeing from all the answers here thus far. Find the event log info and there should be something there to help you, or at least something more to post here.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Server" in the phrase "Server Error" refers to **your** ASP.NET code. You are the server!

If you are running .NET 2.0 or later, you can look into the Application event log (use the Event Viewer applet) for warnings from "ASP.NET". They will include details of what went wrong.

You need to debug your code to find out what's causing this, but the event logs will give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

"Server Error" is just a generic message that indicates the the server code (your code) threw an exception that wasn't handled. It shows the user "server error" instead of a specific message so that no implementation details are exposed to outside users.
In other words, without debugging or looking at a log file or something, all you can tell from "Server Error" is that an Exception of any type was thrown.

Sorry, but the information you provided is not helpful in determining the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the error? Server Error can be caused by various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

- Check for potential infinite loops.
- Check for code in the constructor that might fail (especially for web services).

I think I've had cases like this which led to 'Server Error'. I'm assuming you mean the big red 'Server Error' message?

Answer (score 0):

Save all your files and close your Visual Studio and now right click on Visual studio and run as administrator. It worked for me.